# Can I warm up an IP address using artificial recipient addresses?

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid, spam-prevention

Can I warm up an IP address using artificial recipient addresses?

My company has a fairly large user-base, and we send out ~5000 transactional emails every day. (These are mandatory emails like "order confirmation" rather than promo emails.)

We'll be switching our email provider to SendGrid in a couple of weeks. Hence, our sending IP is going to change, and we need to [warm it up](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/222437627-How-to-warm-up-an-IP-address). However, we are unable to start routing only *part* of our email traffic through SendGrid (the new IP). Instead, this will be a big-bang switch: one day all our customers get the email from the old email provider, the next day they all get it via SendGrid. As a result, our warm-up plan is to semi-manually start sending increasing volumes of email to *fake* email addresses.

Is this a valid approach? Is it sufficient to create one fake email address per email provider, i.e. one Gmail address, one Yahoo address, etc? Is this going to warm up the Gmail SMTP server sufficiently, if we gradually increase the email traffic from our new SendGrid IP to this *single* Gmail address (and then, on the day of our release, we start sending to our actual customers' Gmail addresses)?

**UPDATE on why we can't switch to SendGrid gradually**: We are replacing the whole e-commerce platform (big bang), rather than just switching to SendGrid. This is a mammoth undertaking as is, and we cannot invest in integrating the old platform (which is on the way out) with the new email service provider (SendGrid): that would require all sorts of technical changes (API integrations, access, etc.) as well as functional change (integrating with new Mustache templates, often with modified semantics).

Comment: Your proposed approach seems likely to *harm* reputation, not improve it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? There's no reputation as yet for the IP. Is it our imperfect warm-up routine that will harm it, or the big-bang switch?

Comment: The warm-up routine you propose - sending thousands of emails to one account - is likely to backfire.

Comment: Is there a *reason* you can't send some traffic through Sendgrid initially? I can think of ways of doing this, so I'm curious about why you feel it's impossible.

Comment: I've updated the question with details. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Increasing IP reputation** - Sending emails to one email won't help. You can start sending emails to multiple people around you and in your office at first. Some of them would receive the emails in Spam folder. You have to ask them to mark those emails as Not Spam. This will increase the reputation of the IP. Keep doing this for a few days and the reputation of your IP will grow.

**Sending Bulk emails** - After say about 2 weeks when you do switch your production account to Sendgrid, there will be a rise of 5000 emails from say about 100 per day. This is where Sendgrid will throttle your emails.Email throttling is controlling the amount of email messages sent to one ISP or remote server at one time.  Sometimes ISPs block messages when a high volume is sent by one sender at one time because they might be concerned its spam. So, Sendgrid will help you spread out your emails. You need to send 5K emails daily through Sendgrid so that Sendgrid knows your capacity and keeps processing your emails. If you send 5K emails once and then send 5K emails after 30 days, your emails will be throttled. You can read up more about email throttling here - [Link](https://sendgrid.com/blog/email-throttling-basics/)